# Wordpress erro: "Sem permissão suficiente para acessar essa página"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Meu site Wordpress com WooCommerce mostra a seguinte mensagem quando informo o *login* de acesso:

> .. "Sem permissão suficiente para acessar essa página".

O que eu já tentei, sem sucesso:

1. Deletar aquele arquivo de tradução na pasta *languages* como informa alguns fóruns.
2. Colocar no *root* o arquivo *force-upgrade.php*.

Se puderem me ajudar agradeço muito!

Comment: Eu sou admin @Marconi

Comment: No meu caso, eu havia renomeado os prefixos da tabela para outra coisa que não o wp_ e aí deu esse erro. Renomeei outra vez para o wp_ e tudo voltou a funcionar.

Answer (score 7):

Consegui resolver! Segue a solução encontrada para o meu problema.

1. Entrar no `phpMyadmin/`, entrar no banco de dados usado.
2. Encontrar a tabela `wp_usermeta` e deixar as seguintes linhas exatamente com esse código:

   - `wp_capabilities` deverá ser:

     ```
     a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}
     ```
   - `wp_user_level` deverá ser:

     ```
     10
     ```

Comment: Não funcionou no Wordpress 4.5.2. As permissões atuais são `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}`

Answer (score 0):

Isto tem a ver com o código gerado por:  http://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/

Para corrigir o erro basta gerar outra chave e colocar no wp-config.php, pronto tudo volta a funcionar normalmente da forma mais fácil e simples possível.